# How to aggregate with a Percentage of Total

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is my JSON data:

```
    [
      {
        "_id": "2017/4/7",
        "category": "science",
        "presenties ": 20,
        "absentee": 1
      },
      {
        "_id": "2017/4/19",
        "category": "science",
        "presenties ": 11,
        "absentee": 32
      },
      {
        "_id": "2017/4/19",
        "category": "Commerce",
        "presenties ": 10,
        "absentee": 32
      },

      {
        "_id": "2017/4/7",
        "category": "Arts",
        "presenties ": 20,
        "absentee": 16
      },
      {
        "_id": "2017/4/19",
        "category": "Arts",
        "presenties ": 10,
        "absentee": 21
      }
    ]
```

I would like to display :
   1) Percentages of presenties and absentee per category for each day, i tried aggregate function so am getting the total presenties and absentees

```
[{
        "_id": "2017/4/7",
        "total_presenties ": 40,
        "total_absentee": 17
      },
      {
        "_id": "2017/4/19",
        "total_presenties ": 31,
        "total_absentee": 85
      }
    ]
```

2)but need to mention that percentage in to the above JSON according to the dates like this

```
[{
            "_id": "2017/4/7",
                "category": "science",
                "presenties ": 10,
                "absentee": 21
               "presenties_Precentage":xx%
               "absentees_Precentage": xx%
          },{"_id": "2017/4/7",
                "category": "commerce",
                "presenties ": 10,
                "absentee": 21
               "presenties_Precentage":xx%
               "absentees_Precentage": xx%},{
                "_id": "2017/4/19",
                "category": "Arts",
                "presenties ": 10,
                "absentee": 21
               "presenties_Precentage":xx%
               "absentees_Precentage": xx%
              }]
```

please help me here to complete this task

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? Do you expect the "percentages" to be based on the "total" sum collection wide? Or maybe "selection wide" as per query conditions? It's not really clear in your question what you are expecting.

Comment: i need to calculate the percentage for each absentee and presenties for each day and need to attach that result to the same JSON data

Comment: "Clear as mud", as the saying goes. Are you not aggregating the data for each day? So what is the "percentage" of? The "day" total for "all categories" as compared to "this category"?

Comment: yes i need to aggregating the data for each day then attach that result to the same JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trying to interpret as much as I can from your question, it appears you want to aggregate the totals for each day per category, but also present the percentages of the day total for "all" categories.

Provided the category data does not exceed the BSON limit for a single day then the process for this would be to do two `$group` stages first aggregating per category and then rolling up per day. The day totals can then be used to get percentages.

```js
collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
       "date": "$_id",
       "category": "$category"
     },
    "presenties ": { "$sum": "$presenties" },
    "absentee": { "$sum": "$absentee" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.date",
    "categories": {
      "$push": {
        "category": "$_id.category"m
        "presenties ": "$presenties",
        "absentee": "$absentee"
      }
    },
    "total_presenties": { "$sum": "$presenties" },
    "total_absentee": { "$sum": "$absentee" }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$categories" },
  { "$project": {
    "category": "$categories.category",
    "presenties": "$categories.presenties",
    "presenties_Percentage": {
      "$multiply": [
        { "$divide": [ "$categories.presenties", "$total_presenties" ] },
        100
      ]
    },
    "absentee": "$categories.absentee",
    "absentee_Percentage": {
      "$multiply": [
        { "$divide": [ "$categories.absentee", "$total_absentee" ] },
        100
      ]
    }
  }

],function(err,results) {

})
```

So the key here is grouping everything together in order to obtain the "totals", and then you have the ability to do the math from the numbers that exist.

Comment: the above json is not stored in db , it is stored in array

Comment: @Schüler Why are you asking a question tagged with MongoDB then?

Comment: initially it is in mongodb by using aggregate itself am getting this kinda JSON data so

Comment: @Schüler Why not run the whole aggregation on MongoDB then? It does not make sense to do part of an operation in one place and part in another. If you follow your existing aggregation pipeline with the additional stages here, then you get your desired result.

Comment: sorry will try to run the whole aggregation but am bit confused about aggregation concept and new to node so i made partition

Answer (score -1):

To get the result in percentage based on category & date use below logic

```
    db.collectionName.aggregate({$match:{'category': 'commerce','_id': 
    '2017/4/19' } },{"$project":{"count":1,"percentage":{"$multiply":
    [{"$divide":[100,totalStudent]},"$count"]}}})
```

You need to pass the category as well as data for which you need data. To get the percentage you also need to define the total number of student.

The process is complex.

You can also do one thing find the collection based on category and date and calculate the percentage on node server instead of mongodb.